# MacBook air's 2017 NVMe SSD Trim Support

Tags: macos, ssd, storage, filevault, trim

I recently upgraded my MacBook air's 2017 SSD to 1TB. I used Crucial P2 NVMe SSD with a 3rd party adapter. And it's working pretty well.

Recently I heard about macOS Trip support, I use the Filevault, and someone said macOS don't support 3rd party SSD trim support. But it's already working with my SSD, and I don't even enable it. So I am confused here. Right now, I am using macOS 12.2.

So how is it working on my mac without any extra command? Do I worry about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

macOS has supported TRIM on 3rd party devices since 10.10.4.

If it can figure it out by itself it will turn it on, if it doesn't you can force it with `sudo trimforce enable`.

Of course that's at your own risk because macOS probably had a good reason for not turning it on.

Your screenshot shows that it's enabled.